# G Sheets Table of Contents Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For Google sheet workbooks that have several sheets, I create a Table of Contents sheet that lists all of the sheets in the workbook to increase ease of use for users.
I have looked for an add-on, macro, or script that can speed up the process. No dice. Any ideas for how to automate the process of creating a new sheet that lists the names of all of the other sheets (One sheet name per cell) and then automatically links the cell to that sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expound, this is a great solution except it will not update when you add new tabs or rename/ reorder current tabs. The only solution I could find is to create a simple checkbox trigger.

First I added a checkbox on my Table of Contents tab page. Then I added the script above except, instead of SHEETLIST() in line one I added my checkbox's cell number - for example, SHEETLIST(B3).

Then, I put the formula; in which populates the two columns of data - Name & #GID. In another cell (with plenty of room to list all the tabs) I put the top =ARRAYFORMULA... (not the one with the VLOOKUP) but, again, instead of empty parenthesis after SHEETLIST() I input my checkbox's cell number in both places, like below:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("#gid="&
  QUERY(INDEX(SHEETLIST(B3);;2); "offset 1"); 
  QUERY(INDEX(SHEETLIST(B3);;1); "offset 1")))
```

I then hid the columns with the NAME & #GID data so you can only see the hyperlinked Table of Contents.

Now, whenever I update my tabs I just click the checkbox and it forces everything to reload. Not completely automatic/ dynamic but the best solution I could find.